# Is CDH4 meant mainly for YARN?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I have several questions or rather confusions regarding CDH4. I am posting here since I did not get any concrete information regarding my questions.

Is CDH4 meant to promote YARN? I tried setting up MapReduce1 using CDH4.3.0 using tarball. I finally did but it is round about and painful. Whereas YARN set up is strait forward.

Is anyone using YARN in production at all? Apache clearly says that YARN is still in alpha version and not meant for production. In such cases why is Cloudera making CDH4 YARN centric? Does Cloudera support YARN in production?

Apologies if the questions are inappropriate.

This is how the tarball extract looks like.

[image: CDH4.3.0 tarball extracts]

I followed couple of [links](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/3Pclk0wxUkk) to do a configuration but I am not happy the way it had to be done

[CDH 4.3.0 tarball and MR1](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/3Pclk0wxUkk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CDH4 is not meant mainly for YARN.  CDH5, on the other hand, will be.

I'm not sure how you went about setting up your CDH cluster, but it's rather easy to add the MapReducev1 service, as opposed to YARN, using Cloudera Manager.

Very few companies use YARN in production, Yahoo being the most notable.

CDH4 is not YARN-centric.  Cloudera includes YARN so people can have the most recent Hadoop bits accessible to them - but it's very clear on Cloudera's website that they do not recommend YARN for production.

One of the big things that CDH4 brought to the table last year was HDFSv2, and they made MRv1 compatible with it.

To install CDH4 with MRv1, see [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_11_3.html?scroll=topic_11_3).

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I used tar ball to set up (CDH4.3.0, this packages MRv1 and YARN together). Can you point me where I can get a good setup instructions for MRv1 with CDH4?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the official documentation for MRv1/CDH4 installation.

Comment: Thanks for the link again. I referred to it but it talks about installing from packages. I can't find instructions to set up using tha tarball. I have edited my question to add the directory structure I get when extract from the CDH4.3.0 tarball. Is there a place I get clear instruction to set up from this? I did it by round about by creating symlinks to "bin-mapreduce1" and "etc\hadoop-mapreduce1" directories.

Comment: Rags, as you noted, the link you now provided in the edited OP shows you how to do this.  If you don't like the way this install path is done, I recommend you do a package-based install instead, which is generally a sysadmin best practice.  You can also do the Cloudera Manager/parcel based install which streamlines the whole process as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. really appreciate your time.