# Installing MR1 using hadoop tarball(CDH4.3)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, installation, hdfs, cloudera

When I install CDH4.3 by default it installs YARN and HDFS to run MR1 I have to do other configuration changes .why it does not start MR1 and HDFS and what are the steps to be followed to start MR1?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the tarball is packaged. You need to do a round about method for configuring in MR1. Refer to the below [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231801/is-cdh4-meant-mainly-for-yarn)

If you need any further help, let me know.

Edit:

The files for MR1 have been scattered around in CDH4.3.

1. Untar the tarball into a directory /un/tared/to/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0. Let's refer to this path as  for further discussion
2. Create Symlink /share/hadoop/mapreduce1/bin TO /bin-mapreduce1
3. Create Symlink /share/hadoop/mapreduce1/conf TO /etc/hadoop-mapreduce1
4. Copy old start-dfs.sh and stop-dfs.sh scripts (get the scripts from any Apche dist or from old CDH Dist) and copy to bin-mapreduce1 referred in step-2
5. Add following variables at the top of /bin-mapreduce1/hadoop-config.sh
   HADOOP_HOME=/share/hadoop/mapreduce1
   HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/conf
6. Add /share/hadoop/mapreduce1/bin to PATH
7. Configure the files for the cluster under /etc/hadoop-mapreduce1
8. Start your cluster and check for the daemons

This should set your MR1 on CDH4.3 running. If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: hi,
I am still not clear how i should configure MR1 can you guide me